# onStop() and onResume() SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

Let's assume I have a class and activity, Display.java.
This class main function is to display a set of math problems.
Display.java also has a few variables:

```
  List<Integer[]> problems = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
  boolean addition = true;
  boolean subtraction = false;
```

**My question is: Is it necessary for me to save these variables in SharedPreferences when the onStop() is fired and then retrieve the variables from SharePreferences when the onResume() is fired? if it is needed what is its purpose?**

I am asking this because I cannot wrap my head around the concept that when I run my app#1 and I move away from app#1's process to go to another app#2 (onStop()) and then when I return to my app#1 (onResume()), it seems to be exactly the same way as it was when I left it; and I do not have SharedPreferences in place.

I tried to look around for a specific answer to this, but could not find anything. If you have an answer or can redirect me somewhere I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Two things. First it is not clear what you are doing in your activity and how you are using the values stored in `SharedPrefereneces`. Second if you are saving in `onStop` then you should better read in `onStart`.

Comment: You can save or modify SharedPreferences anytime if you want. if you want save avtivity status, you can user: **bundle** variable, not sharepreference.

Comment: Try rotating your mobile screen, it will redraw your activity and the values will be lost that was prefilled before rotation.

Comment: No, You don't need to save it in sharedPreferences.Variables status remains same if the app goes background until activity dismissed.

Comment: This points also needs to be reviewed:

1. Losing the user's progress if they leave your app and return to it at a later time.

2.Crashing or losing the user's progress when the screen rotates between landscape and portrait orientation.